# Isolated atom calculation in Wien2k

Tags: formation-energy, wien2k, isolated-atom

I am not able to do Isolated atom calculation for finding out Formation energy in WIEN2k. I don't know where I am going wrong, which steps are wrong. Can anyone please list me the steps? What I tried is this - created a 2x2x2 supercell with P structure. Then gave k points as 1 1 1. Tried first by giving spin polarization (saw one line from user guide which said to do it), then without spin. Using the struct file formed by supercell with enough lattice parameter distance between atoms. But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Could you add your log/out file with the error/output?

Comment: @Camps In one try the error was {'FERMI - INTEGRATION FAILED.....STOP IN DOS
 'FERMI' -  RESULT OF INTEGRATION:   11.00000; SHOULD BE:    8.50000          
**  testerror: Error in Parallel LAPW2} ;

Comment: @Camps in another try the error was {**  Error in Parallel LAPW1
**  LAPW1 STOPPED at Tue Mar 19 12:52:52 IST 2024
**  check ERROR FILES!
 'INILPW' - can't open unit:  18                                                         
 'INILPW' -        filename: 1ag.vspup                                                         
 'INILPW' -          status: old          form: formatted                                                             
 'LAPW1' - INILPW aborted unsuccessfully.}

Comment: The idea is that you add all the log/error to your question in the code format.

Comment: @Camps But there is no particular error which I can add otherwise I would have some idea which part is going wrong. The scf itself doesn't start and these LAPW1 errors are on different files. That is why I was asking about steps so that I can cross check.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use a 2x2x2 supercell and not one atom in a large box?
Some useful guidelines can be found at Wien2K site:

http://www.wien2k.at/reg_user/faq/cohesive.html

http://www.wien2k.at/reg_user/faq/cohesive_energies.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3330)